# Unable to use selector to change table row colour

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table, populated from a JSon file, via an Ajax call. Very simply, I would like to change the background colour of the odd/even table rows.

The table is within a Jquery tab; would this make any difference?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

       // $("#table tr:odd").css('background-color', 'red'); <!-- None of these appear to work -->
        $("tr:odd").css("background-color","#eee");





    // ***--- SPANISH MENU ---***

        $.ajax({ 
        url:     "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/spanish.php", 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            drawTable(data, 2);
            }               
        });
    // ***--- CREATE TABLE ---***

        function drawTable(data, table_number) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                drawRow(data[i], table_number);
            }
        }

    // ***--- CREATE ROW ---***

        function drawRow(rowData, table_number) {
            var row = $("<tr />")
            $("#table" + table_number).append(row);
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.course + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.price + "</td>"));
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab-1">Italian</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2">Spanish</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tab-1">
            <table id='table1' border="1" cellpadding="15">
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>    
            </div>
      </div>
```

I've tried .addclass as well, but that doesn't seem to work either. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply the style to the elements before they exist.

`$("tr:odd").css("background-color","#eee");` will look for all odd rows, but because it's the very first line of your code (and the rows are not added until later), it won't find anything. If you wanted to do it this way, you'd have to change the colors after `drawTable()` is complete and all rows are present.

But that being said, using JS for this is highly unnecessary. Just include a simple rule in CSS to take care of this for you:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have placing the script at the bottom of my code, but it still doesn't work. I know doing it this way is unnecessary, but it's for a jscript assignment, that's why I'm doing it this way. I'm just not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Moving it to the bottom of the script won't fix the issue.The code that creates your elements uses AJAX, which is *aynchronous*, meaning the next line of code is fired *without waiting for the AJAX to finish*. Anything in the `success:` section of your AJAX call will run when it is complete, so you'd want to put the line there, after `drawTable(data, 2);`.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you so much.